# Issue installing module sendkeys on mac

Tags: python, selenium

I am newbie python and selenium user.
I have tried to install sendkeys via pycharm ce and terminal.
In both cases got an error.

I suppose this would be the relevant piece

```
 _sendkeys.c:14:10: fatal error: 'windows.h' file not found
    #include "windows.h"
             ^~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Tried with and without sudo. pip, pip3 and pip3.8 to install and no difference.

Comment: as mentioned the installation is not able to find out a required lib, maybe try in a VM or a container

Comment: how did you install selenium?

Comment: via terminal with sudo -H pip3 install selenium